Using buildx feature in docker compose file
I am building a dockerfile that requires first using docker buildx to allow insecure. My current workflow is:

docker buildx create --buildkitd-flags '--allow-insecure-entitlement security.insecure' --name insecure
docker build --builder insecure --allow security.insecure -f Dockerfile --load -t <image_name> .

As there are subsequently a few more other containers to be started, I want to put this into a docker compose file. Is there a way I can put these two steps into a compose file (i.e. using buildx in docker compose)?
